# One to many in NHibernate

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, one-to-many

I have two models, DerbySpawn and DerbyArena

**DerbyArena.cs**

```
public class DerbyArena
{
        public DerbyArena()
        {
            DerbySpawns = new List<DerbySpawn>();
        }
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual short MaxPlayers { get; set; }
        public virtual short MinPlayers { get; set; }
        public virtual short Interior { get; set; }
        public virtual short Model { get; set; }
        public virtual float MinZ { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<DerbySpawn> DerbySpawns { get; set; }
}
```

**DerbySpawn.cs**

```
public class DerbySpawn
{ 
     public virtual int SpawnId { get; set; }
     public virtual float SpawnX { get; set; }
     public virtual float SpawnY { get; set; }
     public virtual float SpawnZ { get; set; }
     public virtual float SpawnA { get; set; }
     public virtual DerbyArena DerbyArena { get; set; }
 }
```

And my mapping

**DerbyArenaMap**

```
 public class DerbyArenaMap : ClassMap<DerbyArena>
 {
          public DerbyArenaMap()
          {
                Id(x => x.Id);
                Map(x => x.Interior);
                Map(x => x.MaxPlayers);
                Map(x => x.MinPlayers);
                Map(x => x.Model);
                Map(x => x.Name);
                Map(x => x.MinZ);
                HasMany<DerbySpawn>(x => x.DerbySpawns)
                    .Inverse()
                    .AsBag();
                Table("DerbyArens");


          }
 }
```

**DerbySpawnMap**

```
public class DerbySpawnMap : ClassMap<DerbySpawn>
{
        public DerbySpawnMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.SpawnId);
            Map(x => x.SpawnX);
            Map(x => x.SpawnY);
            Map(x => x.SpawnZ);
            Map(x => x.SpawnA);
            References(x => x.DerbyArena);
            Table("DerbySpawns");

        }
   }
```

In DerbyArens column Id is Primary Key, Auto Increment

In DerbySpawns column SpawnId is Primary Key, Auto Increment and column DerbyArena is Foreign Key Relationship with table DerbyArens, column Id

I select random arena by this code:

```
using (ISession session = DbSession.OpenSession())
{
      arena = (from x in session.Query<DerbyArena>() orderby Guid.NewGuid() select x).First();
}
```

But when I use

```
Console.Write(arena.DerbySpawns[y].SpawnX + " " + arena.DerbySpawns[y].SpawnY + " " + arena.DerbySpawns[y].SpawnZ + " " + arena.DerbySpawns[y].SpawnA);
```

I get exception

> NHibernate.LazyInitializationException: Initializing[SSS.Models.DerbyArena#1]-failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: SSS.Models.DerbyArena.DerbySpawns, no session or session was closed

**DbSession.cs**

```
public static class DbSession
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    public static ISessionFactory Factory
    {
        get { return _sessionFactory ?? (_sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory()); }
    }
    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return Factory.OpenSession();
    }

    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(
                MySQLConfiguration.Standard
                    .ConnectionString("connectionstring(thiswork)")
            //Your connectionstring goes here.
            )
            .Mappings(m =>
                m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<DbMappings>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(TreatConfiguration)
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }


    private static void TreatConfiguration(Configuration configuration)
    {
        var update = new SchemaUpdate(configuration);
        update.Execute(false, true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are accessing `DerbySpawns` outside of the `using (ISession ...`, while lazy-loading is enabled on it.

Since the session is disposed by the `using`, the lazy loading cannot occur.

You have to ensure no lazy loading occurs after the session is closed.

1. Do your whole unit of work inside the `using (ISession ...`.
2. Or fetch your dependencies inside the `using (ISession ...`:

   - Use eager loading (`.FetchMany` on your query). Beware, combined with your 'random sort', this will very likely leads you to [this bug](/q/7952147/1178314) (tagged as EF but I am quite confident NH would have it too), forcing you to use a [more complex 'random sort'](/a/31245404/1178314).
   - Or trigger the lazy load by accessing the property. If this is just a 'dummy' access, this would be quite dirty...
   - Or force fetching on this collection in the mappings (impacts all `DerbyArena` loadings, will also very likely leads to previously mentioned bug).